# Access minibuffer history without using arrow keys

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer, history

Is it possible to scroll the minibuffer history without using arrow keys?  My preference would be to not have my fingers leave the home row.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html#Minibuffer-History), `M-p` moves to the previous item, and `M-n` moves to the next.